# Programmatically export musescore scores into separate wav or mp3 files?

Tags: musescore

I can already take a collection of musescore files and export them as PDF, Wave, or MP3 without issue via `find *.mscz -exec musescore {} -o {}.mp3 \;`

However, I'd like to expand on this and export each instrument (or clef) into it's own separate wave file (for import into a Audacity or Qtractor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to export as Music XML

```
musescore Song.mscz -o Song.mscz.xml
```

I see that in the XML `<part-list>`, I could use an inline xml editor and change the `<volume>` variable to 0, run the conversion `musescore Song.mscz.xml -o Song.track.x.wave`, and repeat.

```
<part-list>
<score-part id="P1">
  <part-name>Piano</part-name>
  <part-abbreviation>Pno.</part-abbreviation>
  <score-instrument id="P1-I1">
    <instrument-name>Piano</instrument-name>
    </score-instrument>
  <midi-device id="P1-I1" port="1"></midi-device>
  <midi-instrument id="P1-I1">
    <midi-channel>1</midi-channel>
    <midi-program>1</midi-program>
    <volume>78.7402</volume>
    <pan>0</pan>
    </midi-instrument>
  </score-part>
<part-group type="start" number="1">
  <group-symbol>none</group-symbol>
  </part-group>
<score-part id="P2">
  <part-name>Acoustic Bass</part-name>
  <part-abbreviation>Bass</part-abbreviation>
  <score-instrument id="P2-I1">
    <instrument-name>Acoustic Bass</instrument-name>
    </score-instrument>
  <midi-device id="P2-I1" port="1"></midi-device>
  <midi-instrument id="P2-I1">
    <midi-channel>2</midi-channel>
    <midi-program>33</midi-program>
    <volume>73.2283</volume>
    <pan>0</pan>
    </midi-instrument>
  </score-part>
<part-group type="stop" number="1"/>
</part-list>
```